# Trouble Looking For Events WITHIN a Session In BigQuery or WITHIN Multiple Sessions

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I wanted to get a second pair of eyes & some help confirming the best way to look within a session at the hit level in BigQuery. I have read the BigQuery developer documentation thoroughly [that provides insight on working WITHIN as session. My challenge is this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#within). Let us assume I write the high level query to count the number of sessions that exist and group the sessions by the device.device category as below:

```
SELECT device.deviceCategory, 
COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT (fullVisitorId, STRING (visitId)), 10000000) AS SESSIONS
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXXXXX.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01'), TIMESTAMP('2015-06-30')))
GROUP EACH BY device.deviceCategory
ORDER BY sessions DESC
```

I then run a follow up query like the following to find the number of distinct users (Client ID's):

```
SELECT device.deviceCategory, 
COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorID) AS USERS
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXXXXX.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01'), TIMESTAMP('2015-06-30')))
GROUP EACH BY device.deviceCategory
ORDER BY users DESC
```

(Note that I broke those up because of the sheer size of the data I am working with which produces runs greater than 5TB in some cases).

My challenge is the following. I feel like I have the wrong approach and have not had success with the WITHIN function. For every user ID (or full visitor ID), I want to look within all their various sessions to find out how many sessions from the many they had were desktop and how many were mobile. Basically, these are the cross device users. I want to collect a table with these users. I started here:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT (fullVisitorId, STRING (visitId)), 10000000) AS SESSIONS
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXXXXX.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01'), TIMESTAMP('2015-06-30')))
WHERE device.deviceCategory = 'desktop' AND device.deviceCategory = 'mobile'
```

This is not correct though. Moreover, any version I write of a within query is giving me non-sense results or results that have 0 as the number. Does anyone have any strategies or tips to recommend a way forward here? What is the best way to use the WITHIN function to look for sessions that may have multiple events happening WITHIN the session (with my goal being collecting the user ID's that meet certain requirements within a session or over various sessions). Two days ago I did this in a very manual way by manually working through the steps and saving intermediate data frames to generate counts. That said, I wanted to see if there was any guidance to quickly do this using a single query?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this question is still open on your end, but I believe I see your problem, and it is not with the misuse of the `WITHIN` function. It is a data understanding problem.

When dealing with GA and cross-device identification, you cannot reliably use any combination of `fullVisitorId` and `visitId` to identify users, as these are derived from the cookie that GA places on the users browser. Thus, leveraging the `fullVisitorId` would identify a specific browser on a specific device more accurately that a specific user.

In order to truly track users across devices, you must be able to leverage the `userId` functionality [follow this link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en). This requires you to have the user sign in in some way, thus giving them an identifier that you can use across all of their devices and tie their behavior together.

After you implement some type of user identification that you can control, rather than GA's cookie assignment, you can use that to look for details across sessions and within those individual sessions.

Hope that helps!